# SAS Function COUNTW - how to count word including NULL value when using customised delimiter?

Tags: sas, sas-macro

Trying to use the function `COUNTW` to get the number of "words" within a string.
But this string may sometimes contain NULL value when it is comma delimited;

I found some custom macro that can do that, just wondering if I can achieve the same with in-built function, COUNTW for example.

For example:

`%put %wordcount('abc, , ,def,,56j,type',DLM=%str(,));`

The above is a custom function, and it returns 7

`%put %sysfunc(countw('abc, , ,def,,56j,type',%str(,)));`

`COUNTW` returns 6 because it does not counting the NULL between 2 commas (",,")

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Very simple, just look at the online documentation!  `COUNTW` has optional modifiers, one of which is `M` which tells the function to include consecutive delimiters as a word, not null.

The following code returns 7, not 6.

```
%put %sysfunc(countw('abc, , ,def,,56j,type',%str(,),M));
```

Comment: Thanks!  I must have missed it when checking the documentation!  I kept looking for NULL or MISSING when glancing through the page.  Sorry for asking this when it is so clearly written on the documentation page!